# Sequelize update and deduct multiple rows with different id

Tags: mysql, orm, sequelize.js

I have a product table that needs to update multiple rows at once with different ids. still, don't have any idea on how can I achieve.

```
module.exports = sequelize.define('products', {

  product_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER(20),
  },
  product_quantity: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER(225),
  },  
})

var cart_list = [
  { id: 1, curr_quantity: 1 },
  { id: 2, curr_quantity: 4 },
  { id: 3, curr_quantity: 5 },
  { id: 4, curr_quantity: 2 }
]

Product.update({
  product_quantity
})
.then(product => {

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i have checked your code you have car_list array with multiple id and different quantity b'coz of that we have use loop as well as promise.

```
  module.exports = sequelize.define('products', {    
         product_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER(20),
         },
         product_quantity: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER(225),
         },  
    });

    let promises = [];
    var cart_list = [
        { id: 1, curr_quantity: 1 },
        { id: 2, curr_quantity: 4 },
        { id: 3, curr_quantity: 5 },
        { id: 4, curr_quantity: 2 }
    ]

    cart_list.forEach(element => {
        promises.push(Product.update({product_quantity : element.curr_quantity},{where:{'product_id' : element.id}}))
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(resultdata=> {
        console.log('Success-------->',resultdata)
    }).catch(err =>{        
        console.log('Failed---------------->',err);
    });
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer thanks! and it also works.